# Is the Outlook Connection Status Activity table something I can query with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, authentication, outlook, office-automation, outlook-2016

I am trying to locate computers using basic authentication to 365. 365 Sign-in Reports show me the accounts in question but they do the computers (understandably). There are dozens of computers this could potentially be, as they are using generic accounts, there is other ways I could approach this but one that I got stuck on is the connection status activity table visible in PowerShell in some way. What I am looking for is what you get when you right click on the Outlook systray icon and go to Connection Status

[image: Connection Status Dialog showing Activity table]

from https://adamtheautomator.com/modern-authentication-in-office-365/

Specifially I am trying to get the Authn column information to determine more information about the authentication that Outlook is using. Accessing the Outlook COMObject seems like the way to go  but its a dead end for this information as best as I can tell

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application 
$NS = $Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

Is there a way to get the above table programically? Either by an Outlook comobject or some other method that I can use to determine which machine is using basic authentication as supposed to modern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that. As far as I can tell Extended MAPI doesn't have anything on the table for that. That is a specific implementation of the [transport provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/mapi-transport-provider-overview) in the MAPI subsystem.

Comment: `That is a specific implementation of the transport provider in the MAPI subsystem.` Which I am assuming is not something I can take advantage of then either?

Comment: Yes, there is no property or method to request for that.